# How to set initial value for @Id @GeneratedValue in Spring JPA for MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I can not figure out how to set the initial value for the `@GenerateValue` `@Id`.

I have tried using `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` but that is not allowed in `MySQL`.  How can I set the initial value to be used for the `@GenerateValue`?

Using both `AUTO` and `TABLE` I can still not get the initial value to start at anything but `1`

Thank you

**Code**  using AUTO

```
@Entity
@Data
@SequenceGenerator(name = "port_gen", sequenceName = "port_gen",  initialValue = 4700)
public class AppiumPort {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "port_gen")
    private Long port;

    public AppiumPort() {

    }
}
```

**Code using TABLE**

```
    @Entity
    @Data
    public class AppiumPort {

    @TableGenerator(name = "Address_Gen", table = "ID_GEN", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL", pkColumnValue = "Addr_Gen", initialValue = 10000, allocationSize = 100)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "Address_Gen")
    private int port;

    public AppiumPort() {

    }
}
```

** UPDATE **

The problem was related to not setting hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true;

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/ch01.html

Application.properties for Sring Boot:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
```

Comment: if you setup db yourself, you could do it inside your mysql database, if it's not generated with jpa/orm, it's just mapping, without actually creating db.

Comment: I tried with the table generator on the MySQL database and it works perfectly. But I haven't used spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and use the @TableGenerator (JPA has a @TableGenerator annotation in which you can set an initial value). The initialValue can be used to seed the values

Example here : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/SetInitialValueOfTableGenerator.htm

Comment: Check above I also tried TABLE without success. It starts at 1 even though I set the initial value.

Comment: in which case that is a bug in your JPA provider, so you should tell them about it

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "customers-sequence-generator",
    strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
    parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "customers_sequence"),
            @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1000"),
            @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
    })
@GeneratedValue(generator = "customers-sequence-generator")
@Column(nullable=false, updatable=false)
@JsonProperty("id")
private long id;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `@JsonProperty(..)`??? Pretty much unrelated I guess.