# Spring Data Jpa not automatically taking Next Id (PK), it always starts from 1

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.2, hibernate-6.x

I am developing ***Spring Boot (2.1.7.RELEASE) +Data Jpa + Postgres*** example. In this example I am explicitly passing `EMP_ID` value=`100` and next I am allowing data-jpa to automatically take next Id which is `101`. I am not sure why its not working in that way??

Employee.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
public class Employee extends BaseEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "EMP_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer empId;

    @Column(name = "EMP_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String empName;

    @Column(name = "EMP_EMAIL", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String empEmail;


    @Builder(builderMethodName="eBuilder")
    public Employee(Integer empId, String empName, String empEmail,
            Instant createdDate, Instant lastUpdateDate,String createUser, String lastUpdateUser) {
        super(createdDate, lastUpdateDate, createUser, lastUpdateUser);
        this.empId = empId;
        this.empName = empName;
        this.empEmail = empEmail;
    }
}
```

BaseEntity.java

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class BaseEntity {
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "createdDate", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Instant createdDate;

    @Column(name = "lastUpdateDate", nullable = false)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant lastUpdateDate;

    @Column(name = "createUser", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String createUser;

    @Column(name = "lastUpdateUser", length = 50)
    private String lastUpdateUser;
}
```

MainApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class MyExampleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Employee e = Employee.eBuilder().empId(100).empName("Shrutika")
                .empEmail("shrutika@hotmail.com")
                .createUser("Shrutika")
                .lastUpdateUser("Shrutika")
                .build();

        employeeRepository.save(e);

        Employee e1 = Employee.eBuilder().empName("Shantaram")
                .empEmail("shantaram@hotmail.com")
                .createUser("Shantaram")
                .lastUpdateUser("Shantaram")
                .build();
        employeeRepository.save(e1);
    }
}
```

[image]

Even if I used below, still things doesn't works well

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "emp_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="emp_generator", sequenceName = "emp_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name = "EMP_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer empId;
```

Spring JIRA: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1588

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537463/how-to-set-initial-value-for-id-generatedvalue-in-spring-jpa-for-mysql

Comment: @asolanki - I am not convience with the above link, by following : https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/.  Could you please suggest proper guidance ?

Comment: @JeffCook a sequence generator consists in getting the next ID from a database sequence. Not in getting the next ID from the ID you last inserted yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet -  Right. Agree. I always wanted to save records by always doing max id +1. Is there any way of doing this with Spring Data JPA?

Comment: No. This would be impossible to do in a concurrent-safe way, and would be horribly slow.

Comment: As a alternative, I must be saying `initialValue=101` if I already have 100 as a Max Id present in DB ?  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
 @SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=99, allocationSize=1)`

Comment: One approach I have seen is to have a sequence for JPA generated Ids and use negative IDs for ids generated by some other process. Although this certainly qualifies as a bad hack in 98% of the cases.

Comment: @JensSchauder - I am not clear on this. Could you please show some code ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the type `EMP_ID` on the database: `SERIAL` or `Integer`. For using `IDENTITY` with postgres it has to be `SERIAL` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/datatype.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).

Answer (score 0):

> I am explicitly passing EMP_ID value=100 and next I am allowing data-jpa to automatically take next Id which is 101. I am not sure why its not working in that way??

JB Nizet answered that in the comments:

> a sequence generator consists in getting the next ID from a database sequence. Not in getting the next ID from the ID you last inserted yourself.
>
> I always wanted to save records by always doing max id +1. Is there any way of doing this with Spring Data JPA

Again JB Nizet pointed out this is a terrible idea.
It would require a lock on the or at least the index for every insert including the select to determine the next id.

So: **DON'T DO THIS**

If you still want to do it [Vlad Mihalcea describes how to implement a custom id generator](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-a-custom-string-based-sequence-identifier-generator-with-hibernate/).
This should allow you to implement your own generator.
Of course this is Hibernate specific.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
```